# jquery if statement abbreviation with multiple else if

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am setting up a gallery and wanted to know if there was a more effective or shorter way of setting this up.

all the IDs that are being swapped out are called the same apart from a number at the end and excluding the main menu section. I am mainly asking as it wasn't to bad with nine but if I had 200.... well you get the idea.

p.s the code works fine just looking for some tips on shortening or optimizing.

thanks in advance

```
$("#next_salud").on('click', function() {
if($('#Salud_inner01').is(':visible')) {
$("#Salud_inner01").fadeOut(1);
$("#Salud_inner02").fadeIn(600);
}

else if($('#Salud_inner02').is(':visible')){
$("#Salud_inner02").fadeOut(1);
$("#Salud_inner03").fadeIn(600);
}

else if($('#Salud_inner03').is(':visible')){
$("#Salud_inner03").fadeOut(1);
$("#Salud_inner04").fadeIn(600);
}

else if($('#Salud_inner04').is(':visible')){
$("#Salud_inner04").fadeOut(1);
$("#Salud_inner05").fadeIn(600);
}

else if($('#Salud_inner05').is(':visible')){
$("#Salud_inner05").fadeOut(1);
$("#Salud_inner06").fadeIn(600);
}

else if($('#Salud_inner06').is(':visible')){
$("#Salud_inner06").fadeOut(1);
$("#Salud_inner07").fadeIn(600);
}

else if($('#Salud_inner07').is(':visible')){
$("#Salud_inner07").fadeOut(1);
$("#Salud_inner08").fadeIn(600);
}

else if($('#Salud_inner08').is(':visible')){
$("#Salud_inner08").fadeOut(1);
$("#Salud_inner09").fadeIn(600);
}

else if($('#Salud_inner09').is(':visible')){
$(".salud_cont_remove").fadeOut(1);
$("#prev_salud,#next_salud").fadeOut(1);
$("#salud_menu_holder").fadeIn(600);
}

});
```

Comment: We'd need to see your HTML, but yes, this can be a lot shorter. You may want to consider setting up a JS fiddle.

Comment: You could use a loop here with incrementing i

Comment: If you post your html this can be shortened substantially.

Comment: You should post this question at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to have a common class(SaludClass) for #Salud_inner01 to #Salud_inner09 and use the below.

```
<div class="SaludClass" id="Salud_inner01" idx="01"></div>
<div class="SaludClass" id="Salud_inner02" idx="02"></div>
....
....
<div class="SaludClass" id="Salud_inner09" idx="09"></div>


$("#next_salud").on('click', function() {
   if($('.SaludClass').is(':visible')) {
       var idx = $(this).attr(idx);
       $("#Salud_inner"+idx).fadeOut(1);
       $("#Salud_inner"+(idx+1)).fadeIn(600);
    }
}
```